# Fourier transform, deduce $\frac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\cos(2\pi xt)}{a^2+t^2} dt = e^{-2\pi a|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have to calculate the Fourier transform of $f(x) = e^{-a|x|}$ with the definition $\widehat{f}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-itx} dx$.

Then, I have to deduce that for $a>0$, $\dfrac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\cos(2\pi xt)}{a^2+t^2} dt = e^{-2\pi a|x|}$.

I calculated $\widehat{f}(t) = \dfrac{2a}{t^2+a^2}$.

I know the Fourier inversion theorem, but I'm unable to deduce the desired resultat. Could someone help me ?

Comment: Write $\cos(2\pi\,xt)$ as an exponential

Comment: \begin{align}
f &= e^{-a \lvert x \rvert} \\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{2a}{a^{2} + t^{2}}e^{itx} dt \\
&= \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{itx}}{a^{2} + t^{2}} dt \\
&= \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \underbrace{\frac{\cos(tx)}{a^{2} + t^{2}}}_{\text{even function}} dt + \frac{ia}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \underbrace{\frac{\sin(tx)}{a^{2} + t^{2}}}_{\text{odd function}} dt \quad \text{(integrals over symmetric intervals)} \\
&= \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\cos(tx)}{a^{2} + t^{2}} dt
\end{align}

Now let $x \mapsto 2 \pi x$.

Comment: $$\dfrac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\cos(2\pi xt)}{a^2+t^2} dt = \dfrac{a}{\pi} Re \left\{ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{e^{-i2\pi xt}}{a^2+t^2} dt \right\}.$$ That means that your integral is given by the real part of the fourier transform of $$f_a(t) = \frac{a}{\pi} \frac{1}{a^2 + t^2} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using residues you get:

For $x > 0$:
$$I = \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\cos(2\pi xt)}{a^2+t^2} dt = \frac{a}{\pi}Re\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^2+t^2}e^{2\pi ixt}dt \right)$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^2+t^2}e^{2\pi ixt}dt = 2\pi i Res_{ia}\left( \frac{1}{a^2+z^2}e^{2\pi ixz} \right)= 2\pi i \lim_{z\rightarrow ia}\left( \frac{(z-ia)}{(z+ia)(z-ia)}e^{2\pi ixz}\right)= 2\pi i\frac{1}{2ia}e^{-2\pi xa} = \frac{\pi}{a} e^{-2\pi xa}$$
For $x<0$ note that $\cos(2\pi xt) = \cos(- 2\pi |x|t) = \cos(2\pi |x|t)$. So, it follows

$$I = \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\cos(2\pi xt)}{a^2+t^2} dt = \frac{a}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{a} e^{-2\pi |x|a} = e^{-2\pi |x|a}$$